# Calling a page from a table

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am doing this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/tables/creating-tables-in-a-storyboard/
but I can't get `public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, Foundation.NSObject sender)`
to get called when I click on a table.

Why?

[image]

Has anyone had this problem before?
I download their project and it works, but it does not in my project. Why? I am missing something but I am not sure what it is.

```
public partial class ViewController : UITableViewController
{
    protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        CreateTableItems();
       // Add(table);
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        if (segue.Identifier == "TaskSegue")
        { // set in Storyboard
            var navctlr = segue.DestinationViewController as wrestingControllor;
            if (navctlr != null)
            {
                var source = table.Source as ScheduleTableViewSource;
                var rowPath = table.IndexPathForSelectedRow;
                var item = source.GetItem(rowPath.Row);
                navctlr.SetTask(this, item); // to be defined on the TaskDetailViewController
            }
        }
       // var page2ViewController = segue.DestinationViewController as Page2ViewController;

      //  page2ViewController.Name = "dan";
    }


    void errorMessage(string message)
    {
        UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView()
        {
            Title = "Error",
            Message = message,


        };
        alert.AddButton("OK");
        alert.Show();
    }

    protected void CreateTableItems()
    {
        bool check = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
        try
        {
            if (check)
            {

                Service1 client = new Service1();
                var schools = client.School_lists();
                table.Source = new ScheduleTableViewSource(schools, this);

            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage("Error no Internet connection");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            errorMessage("Error no Internet connection");
            return;
        }
    }


    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
```

[image]

Comment: anyone? I really do not see how they are doing. I have been looking at their project and I do not how to get my project to do the same

Comment: Try to click on the connections between two view and look at the properties. Maybe there is a problem

Comment: it looks the same as there. how do you normally set this up ?

Comment: I never set this in Xamarin iOS. I programming only Xamarin forms but I set this in one project in native iOS in Xcode but with list view. Now when I’m have to do something in Xamarin iOS I always use Xcode to write storyboard.

Comment: Segue is linked between TableViewCell and ViewController , you should click the cell not the tableview.

Comment: I do and it is still not working

Comment: I updated the picture